# Jquery Autocomplete additional attributes

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Currently I am trying to pass an additional value from my database to the Autocomplete text field, but finding it to be unsuccessful.

Below is my javascript code for my current autocomplete.

```
    var fullurl = app.php
    $.getJSON(fullurl, function(result) {
        var elements = [];
        $.each(result, function(i, val) {
            elements.push(val.name);
        });

        $('#App').autocomplete({
            source : elements,
            minLength : 0
        }).focus(function() {
            if ($(this).autocomplete('widget').is(':visible')) {
                return;
            }
            $(this).data('autocomplete').search($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Currently this returns the following html once an option has been selected thru autocompelte

```
<input type="text" rel="" id="App" class="input-xlarge ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
```

So once I check what the selected value is using a simple jquery statement such as this I get the App name only.

```
var searched = $('#App').val(); //returns my value
```

How do I pass some additional data into my autocomplete for example an App ID value in the rel attribute. So when I write something like below I get the application ID as well.

```
var searched = $('#App').val(); //returns my value
var applicationID = $('#App').attr('rel'); //how do I implement this? the AppID should get passed thru the db.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is `$("#App").attr("rel") not working? Or are you having problems actually populating the `rel` attribute when an item is selected?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker, I'm having problems actually populating it with my App IDs